# Evaluate limit of a sum that includes summed term

Tags: limits, summation

I am trying to determine whether the limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\left(\frac{n - k}{n - 2}\right)^{2k}
\left(\frac{l - 1}{2}\right)^{k}
$$

exists and is finite.

No idea how to approach this. Please let me know if you can help or have any ideas.

Comment: What do you know about $l$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't say anything about $l$, let's write this sum as
$$ A(n,z) = \sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{n-k}{n-2}\right)^{2k} z^k = \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k(n) z^k$$
where $$a_k(n) = \cases{\left(\dfrac{n-k}{n-2}\right)^{2k} & if $k \le n$\cr 0 & otherwise}$$
For each $k$, $a_k(n) $ is a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative numbers, with limit $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

If $|z| < 1$, the dominated convergence theorem shows that $A(n,z) \to \sum_{k=2}^\infty z^k = z^2/(1-z)$.  If $z > 1$, the monotone convergence theorem shows $A(n,z) \to \infty$.  I'm not sure what happens if $|z| \ge 1$ but $z$ is not a positive real.  It appears you get convergence for $z$ in some neighbourhood of the negative real line.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's not clear to me why, if $z>1$, the monotone convergence theorem shows $A(n,z) \to \infty$? Could you spell out for me why this is the case?

Comment: Also, what happens if $z=1$ / why? Why does the monotone convergence theorem apply here, and (though I think I know what you're talking about) could you state what the theorem you're using says?

Comment: If for each $k$, $b_k(n)$ is a non-decreasing, nonnegative function of $n$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_k b_k(n) = \sum_k \lim_{n \to \infty} b_k(n)$ (whether finite or infinite).  In this case, with $b_k(n) = a_k(n) z^n$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_k(n) = z^k$, and for $z \ge 1$, $\sum_k  z^k = \infty$.